# Bokeh:Common tool for all the subplots without fixing x-range

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible in bokeh to use same tools for every subplots? Like If I zoom(or pan or other activities) on one plot, it should happen on others as well without fixing the x.range(I have 2 different ranges for x-axis)

Comment: Is this what you mean? [linking behavior](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, xaxis_range are supposed to be fixed. But let say, I have two plots, one of them with x axis:(0,200) and another one with (0,4000). If I fix the range, one of them will be either out of the range or look very tiny in comparison with other.

Comment: So you want to synchronize the zoom factor and panning distance but leave the ranges independent? If so, how would you pan the second plot if it has completely different ranges from the first one and the first one is panned half of the X range to the right? If I completely misunderstand what you mean, please provide some example images before an interaction and what they should look like after the interaction.